# Read and write permission for FAT32 partition in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fat32

This is a strange problem: I dual boot Win7 (`sda2`) and Ubuntu (`sda3`) and wanted to use the FAT32 partition to share files across two OS' with the following partition table

```
Device      Boot    Start       End      Blocks     Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
  Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              13        5737    45978624    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            5738       10600    39062047+  83  Linux
/dev/sda4           10601       19457    71143852+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5           10601       11208     4883728+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           11209       15033    30720000    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda7           15033       19457    35537920    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

1. I followed a tutorial, issuing:

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /media/FAT32
   sudo chmod 777 /media/FAT32
   sudo mount /dev/sda6/ /media/FAT32
   ```
2. After I mounted `/dev/sda6`, I can only read but am unable to write to it.

   - I checked the directory permissions, which are `drwxr-xr-x`, but after I unmounted it, it becomes `drwxrwxrwx` and I can read and write to it.

I don't know where I've went wrong.

Answer (score 24):

Try mounting with rw and specify the type:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -o rw,uid=xxx,gid=xxx
```

where uid and gid are that of your user account.

Comment: The umask has effect when creating new files.

Comment: `user` and `auto` are options for the `fstab` entry; they aren't very useful on the commandline.

Comment: yeah i just translated one of my fstab entries to a command line. Left in some bits that aren't useful but they aren't exactly harmful either.

Comment: `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -o rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)`

Comment: It only works _without_ the `remount` option for me (on Arch Linux with util-linux version 2.36.1).

Comment: The files are still mounted under `root` and the permissions/ownership cannot be changed

Answer (score 3):

It's important to repair/check the disk in Windows before using it on Linux, as, by default, FAT/NTFS drivers disable write if they find errors on the disk:

1. Windows:

   ```
   Chkdsk D: /f
   ```
2. Linux:

   ```
   sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/FAT32 -o rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For FAT filesystems, read/write availability is governed by the mount options.

Consult the manpage for **mount** and read about **uid** and **gid** mount options for FAT.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried writing to the files with a `sudo` command?  That *should* work with your current setup.

To get file writes for your normal user working, you need to use the `uid` and `gid` options to `mount`, to set the owner of files on the partition to your current userID.  You probably also want either `umask` or `dmask` and `fmask` options.

Your `mount` command would look like this:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022
# assuming your user's UID is 1000, GID is 1000
# umask=022 sets permission mode 755 for all files on the partition
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply forget about command line and mount with Nautilus, it should set it as you want.

From the terminal, the permissions of the folder before mounting doesn't matter. It's the mount options that count. Try:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -o rw,uid=xxx,gid=xxx,umask=133,dmask=022
```

This will set files to `rw-r--r--` and folders to `rwxr-xr-x`.

If you want other user/group and permissions, for instance to copy files from fat32 to the ext4 partition with the desired attributes, better consult the `mount` manpage. Roughly you put on `umask` the opposite of what you would put on `chmod`.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and the only thing that actually worked is:

```
sudo mount -t vfat  /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -o rw,umask=0000
```

See also [that answer](https://superuser.com/a/617782/169658)

Comment: I did this, the usb key is still write protected

Comment: Did you try `chmod 777 /media/FAT32` ?

Comment: for some reason removing ",umask=0000" worked

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order on the commands you want:

```
sudo mkdir /media/FAT32
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32
sudo chmod 777 /media/FAT32
```

What is happening is that /media/FAT32 represents different directories before and after the mount. Before it's the directory you made, and which you chmod'ed 777. After, it's the root directory of the filesystem in /dev/sda6.

Comment: Won't change it. FAT32 does not understand linux permissions, and the permissions are set by the mount. chmod will not overwrite it. You need to handle it at mounting, via UID, GID, UMASK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without manually mounting, a `fstab` line does the trick:

```
UUID=1DD9-0D44 /media/exthd/TERABYTE_G  vfat      rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,user   0 0
```

- `uid,gid` are of your user; `/media/exthd/TERABYTE_G` must be pre-created
- If `mount -a` isn't applying properly to the new `fstab` line, reboot to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
sudo mkdir /media/FAT32
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/FAT32 -t vfat -o rw
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To avoid the answer being deleted, please edit your question and give an explanation on the options used ans cite a reference on them.

Answer (score 0):

### This worked for me.

- Disks → Select the FAT32 Partition → Edit Mount Options
- Add these two `dmask=000` `fmask=111`
- Check the image for reference:[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MbHG.png)

Comment: Welcome,  please ensure that the answer is valid without a link. Using pinterest for the image sucks. Please try another platform

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes I lose the Windows disk from Linux and I solve using `mount -o force`:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/win -o force
```