# Mount external drive as writeable for all users

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

Okay, the neat thing about Ubuntu is that it automatically mounts any extra drives as read/write for non-root users in `/media`. But, whenever I use `mount` from the command line on Ubuntu or any Linux-based operating system, only root can write to the disk. A lot of people just tell me to use `chmod` or `chown`, but that is NOT what I want to do because it screws up the existing permissions on the drive. So, how can I mount a drive so that I can write to it without being root?

Comment: Seems relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/617777/how-do-i-auto-mount-a-usb-drive-that-all-users-can-write-to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/etc/fstab` to add manually the device (use it with options rw,auto,user). After that, type `mount -a` to validate the job. See the documentation to more options that can be useful to you.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a solution or proper style. The file system table's purpose doesn't seem to be for dynamic drives that may or may not be plugged into the same computer again. I've tried `mount -o users,remount`, but no luck.